# InfoPath with SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath-forms-services

Is there a way to check if a value is already in a SharePoint list from an InfoPath form without code behind? The form is browser enabled so I can not use scripts or managed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a data connection to the sharepoint list and load the list data into the InfoPath form when it's rendered. Then you can use InfoPath "rules" to check if the given list contains the value you're looking for.

If there are many rows in the list the rules can become quite complex. If you can be more specific I might be able to give you a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like Tomso inidcates, you will have to pull the data into InfoPath with a receiving data connection and then perform the necessary logic inside InfoPath.